# Vim set paste in one tab only

Tags: vim

I am editing two files in one vim session (using the command `:tabnew`). I am frequently pasting to only one of those files. It is convenient to use `:set paste` in this one to preserve multiline copied texts (while I am using `autoindent` in the other file). Is there a way how to have `:set paste` in one tab only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily, since paste is a global setting (not local to a window or a buffer like some of the others).

You could work around that by using an auto command that enables paste mode only when a file matching a given pattern is edited:

```
autocmd BufEnter *.txt set paste
autocmd BufLeave *.txt set nopaste
```

You could also define a convenient shortcut to toggle paste mode:

```
nnoremap \gp :set paste!<CR>:set paste?<CR>
```

You can see more toggles like that (using the leader key) in [my `.vimrc`](https://github.com/adambyrtek/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc).

Comment: Actually the work around will work just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Tim Pope's unimpaired plugin? It's a ridiculously useful plugin, and one of its mappings is `yo` and `yO`, which are the same as `o` and `O` except they put you into Paste mode. The best bit is that it automatically exists Paste mode again when you go back to normal mode.

https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired

Comment: Nice plugin but the solution of Adam Byrtek works just fine for me, as I need to have the paste mode in the one file for all time.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a nice command to automatically enable paste while pasting and disable it when done pasting. Basically you never need to be in paste mode.
here is the full article that explains how it is done: [automatically set past mode](https://coderwall.com/p/if9mda/automatically-set-paste-mode-in-vim-when-pasting-in-insert-mode)

This is all you need to add to your vimrc to make it work

```
function! XTermPasteBegin()
  set pastetoggle=<Esc>[201~
  set paste
  return ""
endfunction

inoremap <special> <expr> <Esc>[200~ XTermPasteBegin()
```